# What is the intended way to pass parameters to a grails paginate tag?

Tags: grails, parameters, pagination

I am trying to use grails pagination tag to paginate a list. The list is governed by two criteria, a 'name' string and an 'inCirculation' boolean.

Those two values are passed to my controller's index method as a searchCriteria map:

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    def searchCriteria = params.searchCriteria?: [inCirculation:"on", name:""]

    def criteria = new DetachedCriteria(Copy)

    if(searchCriteria.inCirculation=="on") {
        criteria = criteria.and {
            eq("inCirculation", true)
        }
    }

    if(!searchCriteria.name.isEmpty()) {
        criteria = criteria.and {
            game {
                like("name", "%${searchCriteria.name}%")
            }
        }
    }

    def results = criteria.list(params)
    respond results, model:[searchCriteria: searchCriteria, copyInstanceList: results, copyInstanceCount: results.totalCount]
}
```

The searchCriteria map is critical in making sure that repeated calls to the index method get the same collection of results.

Obviously it is important for the pagination tag to remember the search criteria so that when the user clicks the 'next' link the exact same search is performed, but the second page of results is presented.

I am assuming that the params field of the pagination tag is where I have to put my searchCriteria map, however, I cannot figure out how.

I've tried the obvious:

```
<g:paginate params="${[searchCriteria: searchCriteria]}" total="${copyInstanceCount ?: 0}" />
```

but that appears to turn the searchCriteria map into a string:

```
| Error 2016-10-10 14:52:12,418 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [GET] /halcon-gaming-library/copy/index
No such property: inCirculation for class: java.lang.String. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No such property: inCirculation for class: java.lang.String
    Line | Method
->>   14 | index     in halcon.gaming.library.CopyController
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

I'm currently trying to take the string an reconstitute the map, but the code is getting convoluted. This suggests to me that I'm doing something wrong.

What does the correct usage of the grails paginate tag with params look like?

Incidently, the solution that I came up with is:

```
    if(searchCriteria instanceof String) {
        println searchCriteria
        searchCriteria = groovy.util.Eval.me(searchCriteria
            .replaceAll('\\{', '[')
            .replaceAll('\\}', ']')
            .replaceAll('=', ':')
            .replaceAll(':', ':"')
            .replaceAll(',', '",')
            .replaceAll(']', '"]'))
    }
```

which only works if the user doesn't enter in any of those characters into the name field. That seems super dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<g:paginate params="${params}" total="${copyInstanceCount ?: 0}" />
```